# Problems displaying a form with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm just tryping an exercice to practice vue, I have no errors, no warnings, I double checked the syntax and everything seems OK. Except that when I try the script in the local server, the form will not display. I only see a blank screen.

Sure, this is just an exercise, but I'm very curious to know why this is happening. Here's the complete code.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate); // setting up the VeeValidate plugin
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      name: '',
      message: '',
      inquiry_type: '', // single select box value
      logrocket_usercases: [], // multi select box values
      terms: false, // single checkbox value
      concepts: [], // multiple checkbox values
      js_awesome: '', // radio input value
    },
    options: {
      inquiry: [{
          value: 'feature',
          text: "Feature Request"
        },
        {
          value: 'bug',
          text: "Bug Remport"
        },
        {
          value: 'support',
          text: "Support"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.4/css/bulma.min.css")
```

```html
<div class="columns" id="app">
  <div class="columns is-two-thirds">
    <section class="section">
      <h1 class="title">Fun with Forms in Vue 2.0</h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        Learn how to work with forms, including <strong>validation</strong>!
      </p>
      <hr>
      <!-- Form starts here -->
      <section class="form">section
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="console.log(form)">
          <!-- ordinary input -->
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Name</label>
            <div class="control">
              <!--     Tip: Rules can be defined as objects for more flexibility. For example: 
                                v-validate="{required: true, min: 3}" -->
              <input v-model="form.name" v-validate="'required|min:3" v-bind:class="{'is-danger': errors.has('name')}" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Full name">
              <p class="help is-danger" v-show="errors.has('name')">{{ errors.first('name') }}</p>
              <!-- Other helpful methods include .collect(), .all(), and .any(). More on them here https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/#render-errors  -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- select case -->
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Inquiry Type</label>
            <div class="control">
              <div class="select">
                <select v-model="form.inquiry_type">
                  <option disabled value="">Nothing selected
                  </option>
                  <option v-for="option in options.inquiry" v-bind:value="option.value">
                    {{ option.text }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- multichoice select -->
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">LogRocket Usecases</label>
            <div class="control">
              <div class="select is-multiple">
                <select multiple v-model="form.logrcket_usecases">
                  <option>Debugging</option>
                  <option>Fixing Errors</option>
                  <option>User support</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- multiple checkboxes -->
          <div class="field">
            <label>
                                <strong>What dev concepts are you interested in?</strong>
                            </label>
            <div class="control">
              <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.concepts" value="promises">
                                    Promises
                                </label>
              <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.concepts" value="testing">
                                    testing
                                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- radio buttons -->
          <div class="field">
            <label><b>Is JavaScript awesome?</b></label>

            <div class="control">
              <label class="radio">
                                    <input v-model="form.js_awesome" type="radio" value="Yes">
                                    Yes
                                </label>
              <label class="radio">
                                    <input v-model="form.js_awesome" type="radio" value="Yeap!">
                                    Yeap!
                                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- textarea -->
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Message</label>
            <div class="control">
              <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Message" v-model="form.message"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- single checkbox -->
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.terms">
                                    I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field is-grouped">
            <div class="control">
              <!-- In the above code, we disable the submit button once any errors exist in our form. -->
              <button v-bing:disabled="errors.any()" class="button is-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <section class="section" id="results">
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <!-- loop through all the `form` properties and show
                            their values -->
          <li v-for="(item, k) in form">
            <b>{{ k }}:</b> {{ item }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<!-- While writing custom validation logic is possible, there is already a great plugin that helps validate inputs easily and displays the corresponding errors. This plugin is vee-validate, a form validation library for Vue.js, which allows to validate inputs and build form UIs in a declarative style, or using composition functions. -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.0-rc.18/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Switch to the un-minified version of Vue for some handy error messages. You have quite a few typos (like `v-bing`, `logrcket_usecases` and your `v-validate` expression is incorrect)